# Basic question on pattern matching

Tags: erlang, pattern-matching

I noticed that `[H|T] = [1].` succeeds but `[H|T] = [].` fails. I guess that's just how it works, but is there any reason the designer didn't chose to let this pattern matching succeed and result in assignment of `H=[]` and `T=[]`?

```
9> [H|T] = [1].
[1]
10> H.
1
11> T.
[]
12> [H|T] = [].
** exception error: no match of right hand side value []
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If `[H|T]` would match `[]` with `H=T=[]`, then `[[]]` would not be distinguishable from `[]` using pattern matching.

Further the patterns `[]` and `[H|T]` would no longer be mutually exclusive, so if you accidentally matched `[H|T]` first in a recursive function, where `[]` is the base case, you'd cause infinite recursion.

Also using `[]` as a symbol for "this list does not have a head" seems quite arbitrary and might surprise a lot of users.

Comment: Another way to put it is that it is beneficial to have a way to match in patterns that can discriminate an empty list `[]` from a nonempty one `[_|_]`. You could just have added `lists:empty(L)` or used (the expensive O(n) operation) `length(L) == 0` but list operations are so abundant it is wiser to make up special syntax for them.

Answer (score 0):

While what @sepp2k says is correct, a more fundamental reason for `[]` not to match `[_|_]` is that they are different data types and so should not match. It would defeat the point of pattern matching.